# Security-wise file ownership & permission setup for LEMP server to be managed via wp-cli and wordpress dashboard?

Tags: nginx, vps, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I'm on a LEMP VPS with the following setup;

```
cd /home/$USER/public/myDomain.com        # change directory to myDomain.com
chown -R nginx:nginx .                    # change file ownership
find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;      # change permissions for directories
find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;      # change permissions for files
chmod 400 wp-config.php                   # change permission for wp-config
```

The problem is I cannot get into "myDomain.com" folder without logging in as root. And also, I cannot run `wp-cli` as `$USER`, I have to run as follows;

```
sudo -u nginx wp <wp-command>             # running wp-cli as user `nginx`
```

So, as the title says, what is the security-wise setup for file ownership & permission in a LEMP VPS.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fully covered under [NGINX and PHP-FPM. What my permissions should be?](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

Essentially:

- Always have a site-specific user for security purpose, and that, for convenience is named after your domain name, e.g. for `example.com`, create an `example` user.
- Set up NGINX to be member of site-specific usergroup: `usermod -a -G example nginx`
- Now you can secure things as needed by giving chmod to user bit where PHP needs to read/execute files, and removing group chmod bit where NGINX does not need to access

With the suggested setup chmod 400 for `wp-config.php` will result in read-only access to configuration, only to the site user (and NGINX won't be able to serve it, which is good).

#### Regarding *where* files should be stored

Provided that there are: `nick` (sudo user), and `example` user (site-specific)...:

Website files should be either moved to a user-agnostic location (e.g. under `/var/www/example.com`). Or (slightly worse) be put under the website user's homedir, e.g. `/home/example/example.com`.

If you intend to use a single SSH user for connections,  you can simply change to a user-specific user at will. E.g. if you prefer to always *connect* with `nick`, but sometimes work with `example.com`, you would change to website user by `sudo -iu example`.

Storing website files in a home directory of a sudo-able user doesn't sound secure and is least preferable:

1. if the website files are owned by `nick` (and you won't have `example` user at all), should the website be hacked, they can gain administrative access to the entire server
2. if the website files are owned by `example`, the only way it will work is by lowering restrictions on `/home/nick` from 0700 to 0750, at least).

FHS-blessed location for served files is actually [`/srv/`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/srv.html) which is arguable, but is anyway better than homedirs.

Comment: I'll have 3 users. `root`, `nick` (sudo enabled) & `example` (sudo disabled). Website folders are in `/home/nick/public/example.com`. So, `example` should not have `ssh` access and do not need `home` directory. (i.e. `useradd example -M`). Am I right? And when I `ssh` as `nick`, can I access with `cd` into `example.com` folder? Can I run `wp-cli` without `sudo -u example`? Thanks.

Comment: Having 3 users (`root`, a sudo user, and a website user is fine). But do *not* put one user's file under the home directory of the other. Website files should be either moved to a user-agnostic location (e.g. under `/var/www/example.com`). Or (slightly worse) put them under the website user homedir, e.g. `/home/example/example.com`. Then simply always have a habit of connecting as `example` user (Filezilla, SSH, etc), when you are to make some website related work (using `wp` CLI or whatever). Connect in SSH as the `nick` user (your sudo user) when you intend to do server-side administration.

Comment: Since I already put my website files under `/home/nick/` and I prefer to use single `ssh` user, can I add sudo user to the group? i.e.`useradd -a -G example nick`. Will it work? If it works, what would be the disadvantages of doing it?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: I move my folder to `/srv/example.com` & edit `nginx.conf`. My site is working properly. When I do `chown -R example:example .` , site went down saying `No input file specified`.

Comment: I guess you were not reading the linked article thoroughly enough. Your issue indicates that your PHP-FPM pool is not configured with `example` user. Depending on your specific NGINX configuration also, the `nginx ` user might require access to PHP files (namely for things like `if (!-e $request_filename)` which are good to be lost as they are evil). Finally, of course you need proper chmod on the parent directory for `example` user to be able traverse all the way to site files. Which means chmod 0755 for `/srv` if it is owned by `root`, etc

Comment: I put everything in subdirectories of `/srv/www`. `/var/www` is a system directory and system packages install stuff there. I do not want my stuff to conflict with any system installed files. Also `/srv/www` will have correct SELinux contexts for serving web files.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin `/srv` is already owned by `root` with `755` permission. I replaced all`nginx` with `example` in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/example.com.conf`. Including `user = example` & `group = example` which is not mentioned in the linked guide. But, I didn't touch this line `listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock`.